# Repeating Throttled DynamoDB Requests

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, throttling

I am using the AWS SDK for PHP to interact programmatically with DynamoDB.

I would like to detect if a request to DynamoDB has been throttled so another request can be made after a short delay.

Right now, I am operating under the assumption that throttled requests are not fulfilled. [Amazon FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_happens_if_my_application_performs_more_reads_or_writes_than_my_provisioned_capacity) suggest that a 400 error is returned when throttling occurs.

So I currently have logic that looks something like this:

```
for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {

    $response = $dynamodb->get_item($get_item_args);

    if( $response->isOK() ) {

        break;

    } elseif( $i < 9 ) {

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I suppose this works, but it is a *bit* dumb. In particular, it will repeat all failed requests, not just throttled requests. If there is a non-resolvable error, I really don't want to repeat the request.

To make this smarter, I'd like to look inside a throttled response for a unique identifier (i.e. a specific error message). But for the life of me, I can't capture (or find anywhere on the internet) a sample throttled response.

What is the best way to compensate for the risk of throttling and maximize the likelihood of a fulfilled request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, the AWS SDKs will automatically retry throttled requests until success. So my efforts above are unneeded (since I am using the AWS SDK for PHP).

The [Handling Errors in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/2011-12-05/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html) documentation page says the following for the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException error:

> The AWS SDKs for Amazon DynamoDB automatically retry requests that
>   receive this exception. So, your request is eventually successful,
>   unless the request is too large or your retry queue is too large to
>   finish.

Comment: This also explains why I was unable to capture the error in the responses even though I was observing throttling on the AWS backend.